# Add year/month/day to an UNIX timestamp with just hour/min/sec in python

Tags: python, timestamp, unix-timestamp

The range of my timestamp is from 34200 to 57600, so it covers a part of one day from 9:30 AM). I want to add a specific year/month/day to this timestamp. How can I do that in python? Suppose that my timestamp is `34201.054427731004`. I want a timestamp with information about year/month/day (for example, `3/2/2017`) as the output. So here, the UNIX output is a full timestamp not just the hour/mean/sec.

Comment: Unclear how either 34200 or 57600 "cover a 24h day", or what the expected result is.

Comment: It does not cover 24h : `34200` is 9hours and 30 minutes and `57600` is 16 hours

Comment: @deceze I edited the question.

Comment: Yeah, still not much better. Instead of describing what you think you have or want, *show* us what concrete values you expect to get here.

Comment: Yeah, not seeing how `34201.054427731004` relates to "3/2/2017" at all.

Comment: @deceze I want to know the structure of adding these values. This is just an example.

Comment: So, `34201` represents "9:30", and you want to get the UNIX timestamp of "Feb. 3rd 2017 9:30", or `1486110601`…?!

Comment: I want to know the UNIX version of "Feb. 3rd 2017 9:30". I know that this time (34201) is related to "Feb. 3rd 2017" (this information is in another file).

Answer (score 2):

Make a `datetime` object with the date, which will initialise hours and minutes to `0`, and add a `timedelta` with the seconds to it:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = datetime(2017, 2, 3) + timedelta(seconds=34201)
print(date.timestamp())
```

Comment: Is this consider `.054427731004` part of timestamp?

Comment: If you add them (`seconds=123.456`), yes.